# How do I use rules scheduler to disable and enable a commerce product entity based on certain date fields?

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a commerce product type (entity not display node) with two date fields (enable_date and disable_date). What are the steps to create a rule/component and use rules scheduler to schedule these to disable and enable these products, based on the value of these two fields?

The use case is that I have an event node (product display) that needs to always be viewable but the attached registration (product entity) needs to be disabled on a specific day/time. i.e. Registration is now closed, but users can still see the event info, like location, map etc. Using rules scheduler I am sure I can do this. I have tried with mixed results but I am still learning the rules module. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I deleted my response after you clarified that you aren't simply trying to remove products from your website so that customers couldn't see them (that is what my answer achieved).  Clearly, you need to work with products, and not the product display for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for you attempt Boriana, I should have worded my question better in the beginning. I guess I assumed using the terminology enable/disabled, rather than published/unpublished, meant I was working with commerce product entities and not the display nodes. I have upvoted one of your questions to make up for the downvote I gave you on your deleted answer. I will try to explain myself better on future questions. :)

Comment: Oh, no problem at all, Nigel, please don't worry about that. Sometimes these things come out only from a discussion.  I hope someone else can chime in here.  I, myself, have the suspicion that it isn't trivial to loop through all existing entities of a type through rules (rather than just ones that are in someone's cart etc), but I hope someone else has figured it out!

Comment: It won't have to loop through all existing entities. Trigger would be on product save and then it would schedule the action. I got part of the way there and get the schedule to work and the action I can create but I cannot seem to tie them together. It's probably because I don't fully understand rules components yet.

Comment: Will you accept an answer that doesn't make use of Rules or Rules Scheduler? Is there a particular reason you are tied to it other than perceived efficiency?

Comment: I am already using rules scheduler to add and remove roles for the membership portion of the site. It was created by the commerce subscription products module. It works well and I thought I would use a similar system to expire my products. Custom coding is also not an option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First create a Rules component for setting the status of a product.

1. Go to *Configuration* -> *Workflow* -> *Rules* -> *Components* -> *Add new component*.
2. Create an *Action set*.
3. Give the component a suitable name, such as `Set product status`.
4. Create a parameter of type *Commerce Product*, label `Product`, machine name `product`; and another of type *Truth value*, label `Status`, machine name `status`.
5. Add action: *Set a data value*
6. For *Data*, use the Data selector to select the product parameter's status (`product:status`).
7. For *Value*, use the Data selector to to select the status parameter (`status`).
8. Save

You now have a component that can be scheduled. Next you need to trigger the creation of the scheduled action. I'm going to describe the process for enabling the product; you should be able to create another rule for disabling easily enough following the same method.

1. Go to *Configuration* -> *Workflow* -> *Rules* -> *Add new rule*
2. Choose the triggers *After saving a new commerce product* and *After updating an existing commerce product*.
3. Add the condition *Entity has field*.
4. For *Entity*, use the Data selector to choose commerce-product as the entity.
5. For *Field*, use the dropdown to select your start date field.
6. Add condition *Data value is empty*.
7. For *Data to check*, use the Data selector to choose the start date field.
8. Check the Negate checkbox (we only want to proceed if the field is *not* empty)
9. Add another condition *Data comparison* and select the start date field *is greater than* `site:current-date`
10. Add an action *Schedule component evaluation*.
11. For *Component*, choose the component you created earlier.
12. For *Scheduled evaluation date*, use the Data selector to get the start date.
13. For *Identifier*, choose something like `Enable product [commerce-product:product-id]`
14. For *Status* check the box.
15. For *Product* use the Data selector to choose `commerce-product`.

Then in order to remove a scheduled action if the date's removed from the field:

1. Follow steps 1-7 (but not 8!) immediately above to create a new rule.
2. Add an action *Delete scheduled tasks*.
3. For *Component*, choose the component you created earlier.
4. For *Identifer*, use the same string you used before.

And another rule to delete the scheduled action when the product's deleted would be good too.

I quickly gave that a go and it seems to work for me. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Awesome this is getting me closer. I added to your answer one more condition. #9 Add another condition Data comparison and select the start date field is greater than site:current-date. Otherwise it will still add a new scheduled item even if the date is in the past. One last missing pice is a way to delete the scheduled item if an admin changes their mind and removes a date from the product. The item is still scheduled. Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

Comment: @NigelWaters Very good point, I hadn't thought of that. You can add a new rule with the same triggers that checks if the field is empty. If it is, it deletes the scheduled rule. I just did a quick check and there are no errors if you try to delete a non-existant scheduled action.

Comment: Perfect that did it. I also added one more rule. After product is deleted, delete scheduled task.

Comment: @NigelWaters I'll jus go and add that too, thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Andy. I really appreciate it. Upvoted and bounty awarded. :)

Comment: Anyone have the differences needed to apply this to UberCart instead of Commerce?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I have done in the past and I think will help you retrieve your product ids without having to loop through every single product.

You can use VBO to load a list of entity IDs to your view that you can loop through.  You can read how to do that here: http://nodeone.se/sv/node/777

This will allow you to create two views to return the entity ids for your products enabling today and disabling today.

Then create your RULE to fire during cron or something, as long as its once a day.

Add your Action to load a list of entity objects through a VBO display.
Add a loop based on that loop parameter List. It defaults to "entity_list"
Add an Action for the Loop to iterate over your entity list which is your product entity to either disable or enable the product.  Select Data -> Set a value

Once you are in the set a value part you will see your "entity-list" data selector pop up and you can set the value for enabling or disabling to w/e you need it to be.

Hopefully this will get you where you need to be, let me know if you get stuck.

Just a slight followup, you can add both VBO views to the single rule.  One VBO display pulls all the products that need to be enabled today that you loop through, and then you can create another action to pull the VBO display that turns off the products for today.  So this will run every day turning on/off your products and you never have to worry about scheduling anything.

Comment: I have tens of thousands of products so looping through a view on every cron run is going to be overkill. I would much prefer to use rules scheduler. "After saving product entity, if product has field, compare system date, schedule product for enable/disable" or something like that. I am just unsure how to tie the rule with the component to create the scheduled rule.

Comment: You would only loop through the products that are scheduled to turn on today, or turn off today.  Will you have tens of thousands products that will turn on and off each day?  When you setup your view, you add those options as a filter.  So YOU ONLY retrieve the ones that require an action.  Simple :)

Comment: I literally have thousands of products being enabled and disabled on an ongoing basis. It is an auction site (think ebay crossed with groupon) with a ton of sellers and buyers. The approach you recommend is great but I think leveraging the rules scheduler would be best in this scenario.

Comment: Hmm if it is thousands, I would almost write a custom cron job and query where you can just UPDATE all records that have date of today to Enabled/Disabled.  From a performance stand point, that would be way better.

Comment: Unfortunately the project does call for using rules scheduler. It's directly in the spec. I am just a subcontract in the project and must adhere to the rfp.

Comment: Have you reviewed this? http://drupal.org/node/1582254 and this http://wunderkraut.com/sv/node/1050

Comment: I have now but it is pretty generic. I have also reviewed http://nodeone.se/en/introducing-rules-scheduler and http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-rules-scheduler-part-3 but I can't seem to wrap my head around applying it to my scenario. I have done it several times with mixed results. I thought I would reach out on DSE to see if someone could enlighten me on how to do it for my particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found a good answer of related to this question at Drupal groups. This is really nice discussion about creating rule in Drupal 7. Get the rest of material at https://groups.drupal.org/node/240678 .

Comment: This looks rather like a ink only answer. To avoid the risk of downvotes (or risk of it to get deleted), I would also include at least some sort of summary of what is included in that link ... Just a suggestion!