# Send Mail After Checking Date Field Value

Tags: 7, rules, datetime

My content type (product) has a date field named Expired Date. All I want is like this:

check value of expired date field from content type product. If value equal to 7 days from now, send mail with list of node title and node url.

How to do this with Rules? or any suggestion modules?

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer your question. It will give you are start on what you need to accomplish. You'll need rules and rules scheduler. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64695/how-do-i-use-rules-scheduler-to-disable-and-enable-a-commerce-product-entity-bas

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do this through rules granted the product expiration date is a field.

1. Create a new rule to run on cron maintenance tasks
2. Condition--> has field name
3. Pick your field name
4. Action--> execute custom PHP.

I don't know what your level of PHP experience is so I'll hold off on putting any code down, but the next step would be to write a short snippet of PHP that takes the sites current datetime and checks the values of your chosen field for values that are 7 days away from expiration (rules should give you tokens for both items).

1. Then in that same custom PHP area use rules_action_mail() to send the email out with the results (for reference: https://drupal.org/node/322834).

You could also do this with a SQL query in the PHP area: http://www.barnettech.com/content/dbquery-drupal-creating-sql-queries-drupal-way . Just run through your field in the database and check for the values you need, then return the results in the mail message.

If I were to do something like this, I would implement hook_cron() in a custom module: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7 vs. using Rules since it would require less steps.

Edit: As requested:

See here to make a Drupal 7 module: https://drupal.org/node/1074360

Using hook_cron would go something like:

```
function mymodule_cron(){
 myfunctions(); 
} 

function myfunctions(){
//do cool stuff
}
```

As far as what would go into "myfunctions", it would probably be a query on the database, returning those results, then sending those results in an email with mail(). That would be it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it soon and let you know. Can you please give me an idea about using hook_cron() with this situation..? I'm interested want to use custom module.. since my php level also good. :)

Comment: See my edit above :-)!

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's posible only with rules and one more module, first you have to calculate in days the difference betwen date fields, [here the solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253197/how-to-show-a-users-age-at-the-time-of-creating-a-node-in-a-view/253199#253199), then, with [rules-conditional module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) add an if, add a condition: your diff value calculated is > than 7, send your email.

Answer (score 0):

I've saved this(Someone's else answer I can't remember) earlier because its the best way to do publish/unpublish content based on a date feild (which you can replace it with Send Mail) using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and sub-module (Rules Scheduler)

After you enable them follow these steps:

- at /admin/config/workflow/rules/components/add
- Create a ruleset (name it "Unpublish Content")
- In the Settings/Variables:
- Data type = "Node"
- Label = "node"
- Machine name = "node"
- Save
- ...next screen...Add rule
- Name = "Unpublish Content Rule"
- Save Conditions:
- Content is published
- Data selector = node
- Save
- Content is of type = node
- Value = your-content type
- Save Actions:
   - Unpublish content
- Data selector = node
- Save at /admin/config/workflow/rules
- Create a rule (name it "Unpublish Rule" 
   - React on event = After saving new content
- Save Conditions:
- Content is of type
- Data selector = node
- Value = your-content-type
- Save Actions: 
   - Schedule component evaluation
   - Component Value = Unpublish Content
   - Data selector = node:field-your-node-date-field
- Identifier value = unpublish [node:nid] 
   - node Data selector = node
- Save

Good luck!