# Remove "add to cart button" when event date has passed

Tags: rules, ubercart, datetime

I'm making a webshop that sells tickets for events. And I want that the "Add to cart" button isn't displayed when the event date has passed. But I'm struggling with the Rules module.

Can someone help me out?
I'm using ubercart

Comment: Are you using the Commerce module?

Comment: No the Ubercart module.

Comment: I would still check out the link at my answer below. It might point you in the right direction. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Drupal Commerce, this question seems to provide a step-by-step of what you're looking for.

[How do I use rules scheduler to disable and enable a commerce product entity based on certain date fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64695/how-do-i-use-rules-scheduler-to-disable-and-enable-a-commerce-product-entity-bas)

At the very least it should point you in the right direction and give you a better sense for how Rules integrates with Commerce.

Comment: I'll take a look!

Comment: Ubercart and Commerce are fairly different and while the above link is helpful, it does not answer the asked question.