# How to disable a product variation based on date field?

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a drupal commerce site that sells courses and events. I need to disable the events variation when the date passes so no one can buy it anymore. But, the content node should stay published even if all the product variations are disabled.

I tried with this rules "[How do I use rules scheduler to disable and enable a commerce product entity based on certain date fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64695/how-do-i-use-rules-scheduler-to-disable-and-enable-a-commerce-product-entity-bas)", but they dont seem to work for this because the content dont get disabled.

Can somebody help me with other rule combination?

Thanks.

Marcos

Comment: You can use conditional fields so if the current date is more than specified date you can hide that field

Comment: Thanks! That seem to work, but now I have other problem. The rule only work when I edit the product variation. I need that the rule execute itself without me going to the product because there are so much products.